# Cassandra shows two different rings for one cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

We have a cassandra cluster of 3 nodes. yesterday I stopped one of the node and started it again today. Surprisingly now I have the different ring for the new node. why it is showing as different ring and there are no error messages in the logs.

ring 1: nodetool status

UN  1.2.3.4
UN  5.6.7.8

ring 2: nodetool status

UN 9.10.11.12

When I see the logs of ring 1 both the nodes shows the same message:

> WARN [WRITE-/9.10.11.12] 2013-11-05 14:04:51,221 SSLFactory.java (line
>   139) Filtering out TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA as it isnt supported
>   by the socket

Ring 2:

It has no errors

Both the cluster names are same and both are in the same network and all the three nodes are seed nodes. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but this may be related to [How to remove a node from gossip in cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846384/how-to-remove-a-node-from-gossip-in-cassandra), in that you may have a ring that is a bad state.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue, Before starting node again clear Cassandra cache and hits directory solved my issue.