# How to remove a node from gossip in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

We had 3 node cassandra cluster and we added a node and stopped the other node in cluster. As we thought every thing is fine but we started seeing the hints table is growing.

We find that we made a mistake and remove the node from the cluster but still when we run nodetool gossip info it shows the remove node but it nodes not shows in status command.

What the problem is, We still see the hints table is growing. We don't know whats going on with the cluster and there are no error for 2 to 3 days and all of a sudden a seed node goes down with OOM ERROR.

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space   at
>   java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.write(TFramedTransport.java:146)
>     at
>   com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport.write(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:390

Can anyone help me. We are using DSE 3.1.1

Comment: Can you post the output from `nodetool ring` from one of your up nodes?

Comment: Datacenter: Cassandra
==========
Address       Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token
                                                                             6590989890805234514
x.x.x.1   rack1       Up     Normal  49.56 GB        65.47%              221037599784358654
x.x.x.2  rack1       Up     Normal  44.29 GB        17.32%              3416344233624202454
x.x.x.3   rack1       Up     Normal  67.88 GB        17.21%              6590989890805234514

Answer (score 2):

This may mean that your ring is in a bad state. Check out http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/index.html#cassandra/troubleshooting/../../cassandra/troubleshooting/trblshootRingView_r.html.

This may also explain some of your other issues you posted. You may want to follow the advice in the article (a full cluster restart, not just a rolling one) and reevaluate your issues.

Thanks,
Sven